# How to systematically drop a Pandas row given a particular condition in a column?

Tags: pandas, rows

I have a simple dataframe consisting of 3 columns: Year, Period (Month) and Inflation
I want to remove even months (e.g., February, April, etc.) and the code I came up with is the following:

```
i = df[((df["Periodo"] == "Febrero") | (df["Periodo"] == "Abril") | (df["Periodo"] =="Junio") | (df["Periodo"] =="Agosto") | (df["Periodo"] =="Octubre") | (df["Periodo"] =="Diciembre"))].index
df.drop(i, inplace = True)
```

Is there a quicker way rather than typing those tedious OR conditions to make the index? Like a for loop or something.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas-dataframe-isin) (note the `~` used as negation):

```py
to_drop = ["Febrero", "Abril", "Junio", "Agosto", "Octubre", "Diciembre"]
print(df[~df.Periodo.isin(to_drop)])
```